# Прозрачный отступ у svg элемента

Tags: html, css, svg

есть такой вопрос.

Вставил SVG картинку, но у неё есть внизу прозрачный отступ, как его можно убрать?
Пробовал задавать для svg display: block;, оно в принципе решает проблему, но при масштабировании экрана этот прозрачный отступ все-равно появляется.

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код

```css
        body{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .test{
            background-color: #0099ff;
            height: 400px;
        }
        svg{

            display: block;
        }
```

```html
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320"><path fill="#0099ff" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,256L48,229.3C96,203,192,149,288,154.7C384,160,480,224,576,218.7C672,213,768,139,864,128C960,117,1056,171,1152,197.3C1248,224,1344,224,1392,224L1440,224L1440,320L1392,320C1344,320,1248,320,1152,320C1056,320,960,320,864,320C768,320,672,320,576,320C480,320,384,320,288,320C192,320,96,320,48,320L0,320Z"></path></svg>
    
    <div class="test">
        
    </div>
```

Comment: Попробуйте `svg { display: block; position: relative; margin-bottom:-2px; }`

Comment: Всё работает. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
svg { display: block; position: relative; margin-bottom:-2px; }
```